# how to browse any directory in terminal by command

Tags: macos, terminal

I know just a few things in terminal

cd .. : to go up 1 level of directory
cd foldername : go to foldername which is a direct folder in current directory
cd foldername/subfolder: go to subfolder of foldername in current directory

Now let's say I want to navigate from desktop (which is my current directory) to /usr/local. what's the command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe use

```
cd /usr/local
```

for this...